# how to pivot the dataframe based on the matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have a requirement in python where I have two excel sheets with similar columns like below

Workbook1:

```
breed|sex|animal|area|owner|

abc|M|dog|delhi|def
```

workbook2:

```
breed|sex|animal|area|owner|

abc|M|dog|delhi|efg
```

In this example whenever the multiple owners then it should create the

Result:

```
breed|sex|animal|area|owner1|owner2

abc|M|dog|delhi|efg|def
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1):

I think merging / joining workbook 1 and 2 is a better way to get the result

```
result = pd.merge(workbook1,workbook2,left_on=['breed','sex','animal','area'], right_on=['breed','sex','animal','area'])
```

for more information : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html